# trigger an email automatically upon signup on microsite

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send, microsites

I have to create a triggered email which is automatically sent when a customer registers via the microsite.

Comment: What is the database action when someone registers at microsite? Are you creating a user or some other object modification?

Comment: in microsite use trigger send API ampscript to trigger the email. The logic is when customer clicks on register button it will trigger the email based on the trigger send API

Comment: Abhishek, can you please give a link as to how to set the trigger send API?? Thank you!!

Comment: A couple of less code-y options... Are you using Smart Capture to collect new customer registrations? If so, you could use the feature to send a Triggered Send from the Advanced Options of the Smart Capture form. A Web Collect form would allow you add new customers to a list and use the List's Welcome Email feature to send an email or kick off a double opt in process... http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/solution_guides/welcome_email/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a Landing page with HTML form
2. create a backend page where you will write the ampscript code
3. create a trigger send Dataextension using trigger send template (creation method -> create from template -> TriggeredSendDataExtension)
   Note:
   if you cannot see the `TriggeredSendDataExtension` template contact salesforce tech support they will enable it.
4. Your Dataextension should be sendable
5. By default you will have two fields(`SubscriberKey` and `EmailAddress`) you can add remaining fields according to your requirement
6. goto `interaction` tab -> `trigger send`
7. Click on create -> fill the properties -> select the email in content -> select your trigger send DE in `Subscriber Management`
8. click on save and click on `start/restart` to activate the trigger send
9. in your backend page write ampscript code to fetch the value from HTML form. You can use [requestparameter](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/requestparameter/#RequestParameter) function to fetch the value

Your backend code should have ampscript as below:

```
%%[

set @firstname = "jon" /*requestparameter('your input type name attribute')*/
set @lastname = "doe" /*requestparameter('your input type name attribute')*/
set @email = "jon.doe@gmail.com" /*requestparameter('your input type name attribute')*/
set @subkey = "jon.doe@gmail.com" /*requestparameter('your input type name attribute')*/

SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")
SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", "your trigersend external key")
SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)

SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", @email) /* call the email variable declared above*/
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @subkey) /*your sub key and email address can be same*/

SET @Fname = CreateObject("Attribute") /*Attribute creation depends on the number of fields in DE*/
SetObjectProperty(@Fname, "Name", "FirstName") 
SetObjectProperty(@Fname,"Value", @firstname) /* call the firstname variable declared above*/
AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Attributes", @Fname)

SET @Lname = CreateObject("Attribute")
SetObjectProperty(@Lname, "Name", "LastName")
SetObjectProperty(@Lname,"Value", @lastname) /* call the lastname variable declared above*/
AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Attributes", @Lname)

AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)  
SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)

]%%

%%=v(@ts_statusCode)=%%
```

**Output:** **OK** -> email sent

**Output:** **error** -> email not sent